# Posting json to laravel 5.1 issue

Tags: php, json, laravel, request, laravel-5.1

I am making this post request to laravel (from ios using `AFNetworking`, don't mind the syntax)

```
{
    cart =     {
        "company_id" = 1;
        quantity = 3;
        "service_product_id" = 1;
    };
    options =     (
                {
            "company_id" = 1;
            "service_product_option_id" = 1;
            "service_product_option_value_id" = 2;
        },
                {
            "company_id" = 1;
            "service_product_option_id" = 2;
            "service_product_option_value_id" = 3;
        }
    );
}
```

this is the request laravel gets, im just making it return the request for debugging purposes

```
public function postCart(Request $request)
{
    return $request->all();
}
```

and the result

```
{
    cart =     {
        "company_id" = 1;
        quantity = 3;
        "service_product_id" = 1;
    };
    options =     (
                {
            "company_id" = 1;
        },
                {
            "service_product_option_id" = 1;
        },
                {
            "service_product_option_value_id" = 2;
        },
                {
            "company_id" = 1;
        },
                {
            "service_product_option_id" = 2;
        },
                {
            "service_product_option_value_id" = 3;
        }
    );
}
```

even though the option array being passed consist two inner objects, it is being processed as 6 different object on laravel end. Why is this and how I can fix this?

Comment: Why do you rap the object with brackets? try using these '[  ]' instead of brackets - '( )'

Comment: its a NSDictionary being converted as JSON, thats why I said don't mind the syntax. It is being converted back and forth to JSON while being sent and recieved.

Comment: Is it possible that when it converts to json, it's separating the objects? is there a way you could log the JSON thats being sent??

Comment: @AshleyWrench yeah. looks like there was seperate serializers on AFNetworking for http and json. Switching to a json serializer solved the issue.